# Group the Multiple row item into single row

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

Is it possible to get like this?

```
datetime           | sysname | resource   | metric      | value 
-------------------+---------+------------+-------------+-------
Nov 23,2016 2:00   |     A   |     A-2    | Utilization | 0.30
Nov 23,2016 2:00   |     A   |     A-2    | Throughput  | 300 
Nov 23,2016 2:00   |     B   |     B-2    | Utilization | 10.8
Nov 23,2016 2:00   |     B   |     B-2    | Throughput  | 1080
```

Expected output:

```
datetime          | sysname | resource | Utilization | Throughput 
------------------+---------+----------+-------------+-------
Nov 23,2016 2:00  | A       |  A-2     |  0.3        |  300
Nov 23,2016 2:00  | B       |  B-2     | 10.8        | 1080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT datetime, sysname, resource, a.value, b.value
FROM metrics a
     JOIN metrics b
        USING (datetime, sysname, resource)
WHERE a.metric = 'Utilization' AND b.metric = 'Throughput';
```

Comment: Thanks Laurenz Albe . What if I have more metrics to do the same join ?

Comment: Then you have to change your SQL statement to acommodate them - basically, join another copy of the table for each one.